# Como passar um Array para outro arquivo JS, que será executado em NODE js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, npm, handlebars.js

minha pagina (conexao.js) retorna um Array com os registros do banco, porem quando vou passa-lo para a pagina (app.js) retorna um objeto vazio.

**conexao.js**

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user: 'exemplo',
    password: 'exemplo',
    connectString: 'exemplo'
  },
  function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return;
    }
    connection.execute(
      `
      select * from tabela

      `, [],  
      function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return;
        }
      
        return result.rows
        
      });
  });
```

---

**app.js** (arquivo principal onde esta o servidor e as rotas)

```
const express = require('express');
const { engine } = require ('express-handlebars');
const app = express();
var sql = require('./conexao')


app.use(express.static('public'));

app.engine('handlebars', engine());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});
 
app.get('/listagem', (req, res) => {
    res.render('listagem', {sql: sql} );
    console.log(sql)
});


app.listen(8081, ()=>{console.log('rodando...')})
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Certo, seu maior problema é que essa resposta vem de forma **assíncrona**.
Como funciona?
Bem, leve em consideração que seu código está sendo executado naquele momento,mas o que sua função faz é retornar dados de um banco de dados(que requer inclusive uma conexão ativa).
Dito isso suas funções precisam de modificações para funcionarem de forma assíncrona.

Como ficaria uma função assíncrona:

```
async function nomeFuncao(param1,param2) {
  instruções
  await instrucaoAssincrona
}
```

o que você está fazendo é chamar a função, mas ela não tem um resultado pronto, portanto, deve aguardar o resultado para retornar o valor.
Uma dica, separe as funções da conexão, pois posteriormente poderá usar a mesma conexão para outras funções, tornando seu código mais manutenível

Comment: Oi brother, consegui resolver, na verdade era só puxar os dados como api mesmo, pela url utilizei o comando fetch